# How to add environment variables to "mdkir -p" bash command?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, environment-variables

Lets say I have an environment variable `var="html,xhtml"`. I want to create a directory with subfolders, like so:

```
mkdir -p Website/{static/{cs,js},templates/{html,xhtml}}
```

How can I replace `{html,xhtml}` with `$var`?

Using the command like so `mkdir -p Website/{static/{cs,js},templates/{"$var"}}` results in an odd directory structure:

[image]

Comment: "Odd" directory structure because [brace expansion happens before variable expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/569858/108618), not after.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Is there not a clean way to add the variable to the `mkdir` command?

Comment: The question you keep asking is unnecessarily fixated on `mkdir`. The issue is in the shell, it has nothing to do with `mkdir`. Brace expansion and variable expansion are performed by your shell before `mkdir` even starts. The tool gets the result of the expansions. To expand braces after expanding variables, you need to evaluate again. We have `eval` kinda for this, but [you need to be careful with it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/10765659).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski my bad for not clarifying -- I understood from your link and prior explanation that brace expansion comes before variable expansion :). However, since `eval` is bad practice, I asked whether there was a clean way (other than eval) to do this. The array option in the answer you linked didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will do it :

```
eval mkdir -p Website/{static/{cs,js},templates/{"$var"}}
```

It avoids the problem as explained by @KamilMaciorowski :
[brace expansion happens before variable expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569849/trying-to-make-directories-using-brace-expansion/569858#569858).